# Recommended Products in sitecore commerce 10

Tags: sitecore-commerce

In `Sitecore Commerce 10`, I need to implement recommended products functionality based on previous purchase history. In the official document, I found the [Recommended Products scope](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/sitecore-experience-commerce/commerce-search-scopes.html) for developing Product recommendations based on the order history. But I need to know the steps to achieve this.

can anyone suggest to me how to implement product recommendations with Sitecore Commerce 10?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new commerce pipeline, in which you can pass customerID as a parameter and follow the below steps -

1. In your new block, get orders from customerID/Customer.
2. Then try to get unique products from these orders.
3. Then fill your model with required properties from products and passed that model as returnType.
4. After this you can call this new commerce pipeline from the Sitecore endpoint and show these on the required page.